# Adjoint operator, bijective

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A\in\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$, where $X,Y$ are normed vector spaces. Define the adjoint operator
$$\begin{array}{ll}
A^{\prime}\ : & Y^{\prime}\rightarrow X^{\prime},\\
 & G \mapsto A^{\prime}(G)\ =\ G\circ A.
\end{array}$$
Its easy to show that $A^{\prime}\in\mathcal{L}(Y^{\prime}, X^{\prime})$ and $\|A\| = \|A^{\prime}\|$.

Now, suppose that $A$ is bijective, then show that $A^{\prime}$ is also bijective.

---

First at all, I have proven that $[\mbox{Im}(A)]^{\circ} = \mbox{Ker}(A^{\prime})$, and then $\mbox{Ker}(A^{\prime}) = \{O\}$. Therefore $A^{\prime}$ is injective. My problem is that I don't know how I can show that $A^{\prime}$ is onto.

Please I need help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true in general. Let $1<p<q<\infty$. Consider bijective [bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/114652/19538) linear operator
$$
I:(\ell_p,\Vert\cdot\Vert_p)\to(\ell_p,\Vert\cdot\Vert_q):x\mapsto x
$$
which is set theoretic identity. Its adjoint is
$$
I^*:(\ell_p,\Vert\cdot\Vert_q)^*\to(\ell_p,\Vert\cdot\Vert_p)^*:f\mapsto f\circ I
$$
Assume it is bijective. Since dual spaces [are always complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131822/prove-that-x-is-a-banach-space/131830#131830), then $I^*$ is a bijection between Banach spaces. By [open mapping theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_%28functional_analysis%29) $I^*$ is an isomorphism.
Note that
$$
(\ell_p,\Vert\cdot\Vert_p)^*\cong(\ell_q,\Vert\cdot\Vert_q)
$$
$$
(\ell_p,\Vert\cdot\Vert_q)^*
\cong\left(\operatorname{completion}(\ell_p,\Vert\cdot\Vert_q)\right)^*
\cong(\ell_q,\Vert\cdot\Vert_q)^*
\cong(\ell_p,\Vert\cdot\Vert_p)
$$
so using that $I^*$ is an isomorphism we see that $(\ell_p,\Vert\cdot\Vert_p)$ and $(\ell_q,\Vert\cdot\Vert_q)$ are isomorphic via some operator $J$. But [this is impossible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99086/how-do-you-prove-that-ell-p-is-not-isomorphic-to-ell-q), so we get a contradiction. Thus $I^*$ is not bijective, though  $I$ is bijective.

On the other hand, if you assume that $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces then you have an equivalence
$$
A\text{ is bijective}\Longleftrightarrow A'\text{ is bijective}
$$ 
For proof see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398450/if-tx-to-y-is-a-linear-homeomorphism-is-its-adjoint-t-a-linear-homeomor/398455#398455) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346560/show-t-is-invertible-if-t-is-invertible-where-t-in-bx-t-in-bx/346640#346640) answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the statement is true when the spaces are not complete. Let $X$ be the space of differentiable functions on $[-1,1]$ with the $C^1$ norm, and let $Y$ be the same set of functions, but equipped with the $C^0$ norm. Let $A$ be the identity map. It is certainly continuous, since $\|f\|_0 \leq \|f\|_1$.

Now, let $T(f) = f'(0)$. This is in $X'$, but is not the image of any operator under $A'$. Suppose $S: Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ were such an operator. Then $S(f) = T(f)$. But this means that differentiation at $0$ is a continuous map on $Y$. But there are functions bounded by 1 that have arbitrarily large derivatives at 0.